# How can I POST a value for the Google Sheets API V4 in Swift 3 and 4?

Tags: ios, post, swift4, google-sheets-api

I have been trying to do this for about two days and I am unfortunately not understanding this API or able to translate the documentation from one language to another. Any ways I am trying to do a POST request for the Google sheets by using Swift 4.

So far I have successfully done a GET request. with this code:

```
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets, kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsDrive]
private let service = GTLRSheetsService()
let signInButton = GIDSignInButton()
let output = UITextView()
var requestType = ""

func gIDPrepare(){
    // Configure Google Sign-in.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    // Add the sign-in button.
    view.addSubview(signInButton)

}

//GET request for specific tab
//grab the hash and store it
func professorGET(){
    requestType = "PG"
    gIDPrepare()
}


public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        showAlert("problem", message: "Authentication Error", action: error.localizedDescription)
        self.service.authorizer = nil
    } else {
        self.signInButton.isHidden = true
        self.output.isHidden = false
        self.service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
        switch requestType {
            case "SG":
                getCells(cellRange: "A1:B")
            case "PG":
                getCells(cellRange: "SHA!B3:B3")
            case "PP":
                postCells(range: "Test!A1:D1")
            default:
                print("something wrong happened")
        }
    }

func getCells(cellRange:String) {
    output.text = "Getting sheet data..."
    let spreadsheetId = "sheetid"
    let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet.query(withSpreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range:cellRange)
    service.executeQuery(query, delegate: self, didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rejoice your answerer is here to help if you have any questions!(: Although I must say I don't recommend this because it can make your System more coupled.

Anyways this is how I successfully made a POST with the Google Sheets API V4 using Swift 3 and 4.

1. First off make sure you have completed the directions on [this link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) and done a GET so you have properly unit tested I used these version with my pod file.

   `pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Sheets', '~> 1.2.1'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.1.1'`
2. After that you will need to increase your scopes. So change that instance variable to:

   `private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets, kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsDrive]`
3. Finally change this inside of the method listMajors() from the Setup Google provides. To this:

   ```
   func listMajors(){

       let range = "SheetName!A1:A2"
       let spreadsheetId = "your sheet id as string"
       let descriptions: [String: Any] = ["range" : range,
                                      "majorDimension" : "ROWS",
                                      "values" : [["dog"], ["cat"]]
                                     ]
       let valueRange = GTLRSheets_ValueRange(json: descriptions)
       let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate.query(withObject: valueRange, spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range: range)
       query.valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED"
       service.executeQuery(query, delegate: self, didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))

   }
   ```

Comment: SIR Aaron! And yes I say Sir. Long story short you just helped me put to rest a YEAR and a HALF long battle with this API stuff. Thank you sooooo much for sharing what you learned on here. Also tip of the hat to you for answering your own question. I know how hard it is to find resources for GoogleAPIS in swift. Thank you once more!!!

Comment: Happy to help @MichaelSzabo! This was no doubt a very tough thing to find in my opinion. LOTS of trial and error.